# Remover espaço entre span e input

Tags: html, css

Quero saber como posso remover estes espaços: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para que o `span`e o `input`fiquem juntos, como aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu CSS**:

```
input, textarea { 
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; 
border: 1px solid #C9C9C9; 

color: #545658; 
padding: 8px; 
font-size: 14px; 
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px; 

}
 .input-group-addon {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
  }
```

**MEU HTML**:

```
<div class="input-group1">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nome</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" />

    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email</span>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="input_email" />
</div>
<div class="input-group1">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Empresa</span>
    <input type="text" name="empresa" class="input_empresa" />
    <select name="state" class="btn" data-width="76" data-value="Funcionários">
        <option value="">Funcionários</option>
        <option value="">------</option>
    </select>
            </div>

    <div class="input-group1">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Cidade</span>
        <input type="text" name="cidade" class="input_cidade" />

    <input type="hidden" name="form_input" value="FORM_COTACAO" />
                <select name="state" class="btn" data-width="76" data-value="UF*">
                    <option value="">UF</option>
                    <option value="AC">AC</option>
                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                    <option value="AP">AP</option>
                    <option value="AM">AM</option>
                    <option value="BA">BA</option>
                    <option value="CE">CE</option>
                    <option value="DF">DF</option>
                    <option value="ES">ES</option>
                    <option value="GO">GO</option>
                    <option value="MA">MA</option>
                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                    <option value="MS">MS</option>
                    <option value="MG">MG</option>
                    <option value="PA">PA</option>
                    <option value="PB">PB</option>
                    <option value="PR">PR</option>
                    <option value="PE">PE</option>
                    <option value="PI">PI</option>
                    <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
                    <option value="RN">RN</option>
                    <option value="RS">RS</option>
                    <option value="RO">RO</option>
                    <option value="RR">RR</option>
                    <option value="SC">SC</option>
                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                    <option value="SE">SE</option>
                    <option value="TO">TO</option>
                </select>   
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Telefone</span>
        <input type="text" name="telefone" class="input_telefone" />
        <div class="input-group">

</div>  

</div>
```

*Sei que poderia fazer o formulário facilmente utilizando bootstrap, mas foi me pedido para que não utilizasse neste projeto.*

Comment: Provavelmente seu input ou span esta com margem. Tente adicionar `margin: 0`. Nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor (tanto FF quanto do Chrome), na aba "Elementos" há a opção de ver em formato de caixa um elemento selecionado. Nesta formato de caixas, são exibidos padding, largura, altura e margens computadas. Assim você pode saber certinho qual delas esta causando o espaço. Pessoalmente, acho mais provável que jsea o `input`.

Comment: Caminho mais curto: remova qualquer espaço ou quebra de linha entre esses elementos no seu HTML. Isso ocorre com elementos *inline* e *inline-block*.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira Obrigado pelo comentário e pela explicação!

Comment: @bfavaretto Funcionou certinho! Nunca imaginei que seria isso, muito obrigado!

Comment: @GWER Posta a solução que encontrou como resposta.

Comment: esse problema é bem chato mesmo... no SO-en tem uma pergunta com diversas soluções interessantes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nome</span>
<input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" />
```

Coloque a tag **input** ao lado da tag **span** da seguinte forma:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nome</span><input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" />
```

Fazendo isso, os elementos ficarão um do lado do outro sem conter espaçamento. Sugiro aplicar a tag **label** entre os elementos para melhorar a acessibilidade. Do resto do seu código, basta fazer o mesmo procedimento.

Answer (score 1):

Colocando flutuabilidade, você resolve o seu problema. Veja esta [pen](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/NqxmwP).

Obviamente, você precisa criar uma marcação a mais para envolver os blocos e dispor os elementos da maneira que achar melhor. Mas dessa maneira, o espaço em branco some.